# How to use google Navbar with Riverpod?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm using `flutter-riverpod` for state management in my app. Since for using Riverpod, I have to change my `Stateful widget` into a `consumer widget`, I couldn't access `setState()`. Now, after writing state management code for bottom bar using `Riverpod`, it does not work.

Here is my code-

```
int index = 0;

class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  final currentIndex = Provider<int>((ref) => index);

  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    int _currentIndex = watch(currentIndex);

    

    return auth.when(//authstatchange provider
      data: (e) {
        if (e!=null&&e.uid != null) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: PageView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: (ind) {
                index = ind;
              },
              children: [
                SomePage(),
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Container(
                someCode(),
),
                child: SomeCode(),)
                        tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
                        tabs: [
                          tabs()
                        ],
                        selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
                        onTabChange: (ind) {
                          index = ind;
                         _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
                        )//closing brackets (omitted)
   //brackets
```

Comment: Has been some time - but this looks like a duplicate of this earlier question, that has an accepted answer written by Remi R, the creator of Riverpod. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64435989/flutter-navigationbar-with-riverpod

Answer (score -1):

Solved, if you use state Provider then rebuild state.
[image: state]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33037117)